# C# - DataTable Select columns with null value LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, rows

I'm converting an Excel file to a DataTable and I want to check if there is any null value in the columns. Is there a way to do it without specify the column name? Something like:

```
var nullValues = excelTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.IsNull(0));
```

But without specify the column index?

Comment: Is the type of `excelTable` a `DataTable`?

Comment: Yes, it's a DataTable

Comment: @AndreVillanueva Welcome to [so]! You've asked two separate questions, which makes it hard to answer them independently, and vote on answers to each question independently. I've edited out your second question. You should ask a separate question for that. The text of your second answer is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48350739/revisions).

Comment: There is just the question, not the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the fields exist in a DataTable and find null values. Keep in mind that you need to check the values against DBNull. This type designed before .NET introduced Nullable types.

"DBNull represents a nonexistent value returned from the database. In a database, for example, a column in a row of a table might not contain any data. The column is considered to not exist at all instead of merely not having a value." [Reference.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/handling-dbnull-in-c-sharp1)

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var cols = new[]
{
    new DataColumn("OrderDetailId", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("OrderId", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Product", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("UnitPrice", typeof(decimal)),
    new DataColumn("OrderQty", typeof(int))
};
dt.Columns.AddRange(cols);


object[] rows =
{
    new object[] {1, "O0001", "Mountain Bike", 1419.5, 36},
    new object[] {2, "O0001", "Road Bike", 1233.6, 16},
    new object[] {3, "O0001", "Touring Bike", 1653.3, 32},
    new object[] {4, "O0002", null, 1419.5, 24},
    new object[] {5, "O0002", "Road Bike", 1233.6, 12},
    new object[] {6, "O0003", "Mountain Bike", null, 48},
    new object[] {7, "O0003", "Touring Bike", 1653.3, 8},
};

foreach (object[] row in rows)
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

var dtRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList();
var rowsWithNullValue = dtRows.Where(x => x.Any(y => y == null || y == DBNull.Value)).ToList();

if (dtRows.Any(x => x.Any(y => y == null || y == DBNull.Value)))
{
    var nullRecordCount = rowsWithNullValue.SelectMany(x => x).Count(x => x == null || x == DBNull.Value);
    Console.WriteLine($"The table contains ({nullRecordCount}) null values.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the datarow's ItemArray with linq to check for any nulls:

```
var nullValues = excelTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.ItemArray.Any(v=>v is DBNull));
```

Comment: I've removed the second question ([see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350739/c-sharp-datatable-select-columns-with-null-value-linq#comment83689073_48350739)), and edited your answer to match. Remember that your original is in the edit history if you disagree. Thanks!