# How to handle a linq statement that queries a datatable where no rows are returned

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple datatable like this:

```
F1   F2
A     1
B     2
```

I want to return the value of F2 where F1 is a certain value. This code works when the row exists:

```
DataTable dt = null;
DataRow dr = null;
string strTemp = null;

//define datatable
dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("F1");
dt.Columns.Add("F2");

//add 2 rows
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["F1"] = "1";
dr["F2"] = "A";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["F1"] = "2";
dr["F2"] = "B";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

//this returns "A"
strTemp =
    dt.AsEnumerable().
    Where(x => x.Field<string>("F1") == "1").
    FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("F2");
```

But I get a value cannot be null error when I try to search for a value that does not exist:

```
strTemp =
    dt.AsEnumerable().
    Where(x => x.Field<string>("F1") == "123"). //this gets an error because 123 does not exist
    FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("F2");
```

How can I handle this? (Also is this best practice for doing the search?)

Comment: Does this existing post and response help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350739/c-sharp-datatable-select-columns-with-null-value-linq

Comment: No sorry, it does not.

Comment: "How can I handle this?" check for a null value before asking for the value of the `F2` field. There are multiple ways to do that, depending on what you want the value of `strTemp` to be in that scenario.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()?.Field<string>("F2")` would be the easiest, but you need to make sure you know _why_ it works.

Comment: @ D Stanley - Yes, that's basically my question. How do I check for no records returned?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` will return null if no records are found. So capture that first and check it for null. If it's not null, then get the value of the `F2` field. The `?.` operator encapsulates that if you want the result to be `null` if no record is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var strTemp =
    dt.AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("F1") == "123")
    ?.Field<string>("F2");
```

It's not the `.Where` that is erroring; it's the attempt to call `.Field()` on the null returned from `.FirstOrDefault()`. If you use `?.Field` instead, then the method won't actually be called if FOD has returned null, it'll just zip straight to setting `strTemp` to `null`. See [null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) in the fine manual for more info

(So bear that in mind before you use `strTemp`)

> How do I check for no records returned?

That's a slightly different question, and probably obviated by the above, but you can look at `Enumerable.Any` if you want to know for other contexts

> Also is this best practice for doing the search?

For datatables, it's more performant to search on the primary key, or if you will do a lot of searching in a column, index it with perhaps:

```
var lu = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToLookup(r => (string)r["F1"])
```

This would generate a lookup that you can use to quickly search for all DataRow with "Hello" in F2:

```
foreach(var ro in lu["Hello"])
  ...
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Madison320 NP. I added some other bits you asked about too..